# Center search bar, justifyContent not working

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to center the search bar in my screen. I am using justifyContent to attempt to do so. I could always use padding to achieve this but I feel like I should not have to? I am assuming I am missing something simple.

I am using https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/searchbar/#containerstyle

Thank you for any insight at all!

[image]

```
 <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#272933', }}>
<SearchBar
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
        value={search}
        round='true'
        containerStyle={{marginTop: scale(15), backgroundColor: '#272933', borderBottomColor: 'transparent', borderTopColor: 'transparent', 
        display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}
        inputContainerStyle={{height: scale(30),  width: scale(200),justifyContent: 'center'}}
        searchIcon={() => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="glass-mug-variant" size={30} color='#87909A'/>}
        clearIcon= 'null'
      />
```

Answer (score 2):

`justifyContent` works properly for the `display:flex`.

You should add `display: 'flex'` style as well.

Comment: I added it to my edit above, what am I misinterpreting?

Comment: add it in `containerStyle`.

Comment: I tried that, as well as with it only in container, only in input, and both.

Comment: fyi, you removed `justifyContent: center`. once you add it, update your question with the result

Comment: can you see the width of the parent of SearchBar using inspect element?

Comment: Assuming I need the chrome developer tools for that? I am running it on snack expo

Comment: can you attach the codebase for parent of SearchBar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231349/discussion-between-justin-priede-and-william-wang).